# Close window which called servlet from another context root but same domain

Tags: java, javascript, jsp, servlets

I m calling sendMail utility from one context to another context path like

from `www.test.com/app1/utility`

here i m calling servlet for send mail like

```
www.test.com/app2/sendMailServlet
```

now i second  servlet window opened in new window and after sending mail i wil return null so page would be staying as it is.

now i want to close this servlet window(`www.test.com/app2/sendMailServlet`) after senidng mail and want some feed back on parent context window (`www.test.com/app1/utility`).

How can i achieve this ?

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Ok so your saying you want to come back to the parent window after sending your mail??

Comment: yes but the parent window has context root and servlet context root r different.